# Failed to install the requested application

Tags: ios, xcode

I am migration all the pods from Xcode 10.1 to Xcode 10.2.1 , compiles everything. When it's time to open the application, seeing below error

"Failed to installed the request application"

The application's CFBundleVersion is invalid

[image: s]

Comment: Did you review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+application%27s+CFBundleVersion+is+invalid)?

Comment: tried cleanign everything , cache from below link (https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache ) still issue persists even on Xcode 10.1

Comment: Fixed the issue by following below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450295/cannot-run-application-on-simulator-after-installing-xcode-11-cfbundleversion