# iOS: How to upgrade my CFBundleVersion and my CFBundleShortVersionString automatically in Xcode 11? (My old script doesn't work anymore)

Tags: ios, xcode, versioning, run-script

I have a script that upgraded my version (0.01 by 0.01) and my build (1 by 1). It doesn't work anymore with the Xcode 11.

[image]

Here is my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    rm -rf build

    Version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
    Version=$(echo "scale=2; $Version + 0.01" | bc)

    Build=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
    Build=$($Build + 1)

    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $Build" 

    "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
        if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $Version" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"    
fi
```

Here is the Error message I have now when I want to build or archive in Xcode:

> Details
>
> Failed to install the requested application
>   Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code: 22
>   Failure Reason: The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleShortVersionString.
>   Recovery Suggestion: Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleShortVersionString.
>   User Info: {
>      bundleURL = "file:///Users/olosta/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Formbox-cxaxehrhmxqaqabbijmxvasgmhwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Formbox_Renault_BusinessDays.app/";
>   }

I checked that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450295/cannot-run-application-on-simulator-after-installing-xcode-11-cfbundleversion), but it doesn't help me for the script

If I go in Xcode/General/Identity, I can see that the "Version" and the "Build" are filled in the Xcode,  [image] but if I check my info.plist by manually opening it, both values are empty

```
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>               <string></string>    
   <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>    <string></string>
```

If I fill them manually directly in the plist, it works but it seems that the values from Xcode are not stored in that fields anymore? What do you think?

Comment: Why not set both `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` regardless of `$CONFIGURATION`?

Comment: @trojanfoe because I just want the Version upgrading with the archiving, and the build each time I compile, or build or archive etc... That part works well, no problem.

Comment: Well it looks to me like you are generating an invalid `Info.plist`.  Just *increase* `Version` when arciving but always set it.

Comment: I've just post this answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636744/7332815)
hope it help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete script. I tried it with old and new projects.

```
 #!/bin/bash
rm -rf build

Build=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
Version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")

if [ "${Build}" = "" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion 1" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"   
else
Build=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
Build=$(echo "scale=0; $Build + 1" | bc)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $Build" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
if [ "${Version}" = "" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString 1.00" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
else
Version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
Version=$(echo "scale=2; $Version + 0.01" | bc)
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $Version" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
fi
```

EDIT:
For completing the solution, I added that keys in the plist. I changed the existing values by:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.00</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
```

Comment: Thks it works. It is strange because the marketing version is not changing anymore, but it works. Very strange. I will see if it is a tolerance from Apple for now, may be they don't allow it later and I may find the way to upgrade the "marketing version"...

Comment: for me adding CFBundleShortVersionString to my plist was the solution, thanks for freeing me up on this one.

Answer (score 5):

You can try with:

```
versionNumber="$MARKETING_VERSION"
buildNumber="$CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION"
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722677/how-to-read-current-app-version-in-xcode-11-with-script)

Comment: If you question is a dupe then why answer it?

Comment: @dt dino Oh, it is interesting, that is why there is problems, they changed something in the info.plist. I try to get it in the script, but impossible to set the New CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION...