# Unable to upload Xamarin.ios solution to TestFlight cause of following error:

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

We have an update scheduled for our iOS app which needs to be uploaded to TestFlight first. Hovever, just out of nowhere, the following error keeps preventing Visual Studio from uploading the solution to TestFlight:

[This is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWzaW.png)

I am relatively new to this and have no clue where to look in VS. And I've already been searching everywhere online..

Some extra info:
Visual Studio for Mac (latest version)
macOS Big Sur (11.2.3 - latest)

I do believe this might have something to do with the implementation of Firebase into my app. But being a relative newbie, I'm also not entirely sure where to look..

I'd love to hear from anyone with a solution!!

Comment: Does it work when archive it as a normal ipa ?

Comment: @Lucas Zhang Yes it only happens when directly uploading it to the app store connect from VS. But the IPA is created successfully.
I've already tried to upload the IPA via the Transporter app which also didn't work.

Comment: There are som interesting things in this answer that might relate to your former problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56536439/4837902

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

For some reason all I had to do was get rid of the old xCode version I had and download the latest from apple's website rather than the app store...